# Swift 4 can't pop a view controller

Tags: swift

I have this code in my Swift 4 code

```
      _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

What i want to do is to return back to the previous viewcontroller.But unfortunately nothing happens.I also tried doing it without `_ =`,but it was also a fruitless action.

Comment: Are u sure that `navigationController` is not `nil`? it could be present/dismiss...

Comment: @AhmadF i printed `self. navigationController ` and it didn't return nil

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume that the `self.navigationController` property is nil. Have you tried a force unwrap `self.navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)`? If it is `nil` it will crash.

Comment: but when i type `self. navigationController` it still autocompletes,wouldn't that indicate that it's not nil?

Comment: Nope. Autocomplete has nothing to do with the property being nil. You can only determine if the property is nil at runtime not compile time.

Comment: It didn't crash when force unwrapping,but after i click back the page becomes white for few seconds

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
self.navigationController?.viewControllers
```

To see what are the controllers in the stack.

Seems to me that you either don't have the controller you want to pop inside a navigation controller or that the previous one is just a empty controller (hence is all white)